# What happen if I remain to use old Xcode version?

Tags: xcode, xcode11, xcode12

I'm trying to understand, what will happen if one remains to use older Xcode version for developing, building and deploying.

I understand that each new Xcode version (...10,11,12) comes with new SDK support, improvements and features. I also have a great example of, we'll need the latest Xcode 12 to deploy our app to iOS 14 and above, since it won't work for Xcode 11 and below.

**[Scenario ques]**

However, what are the possible issues if one decided to continue in building and deploying their app with Xcode 11(SDK iOS13)?

Aside from not being able to test the app in a proper iOS 14 environment and risking of having bugs. Could the SDK version in Xcode11 and Xcode12 make any difference to the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly go on playing with Xcode 11 if that is what you feel like doing. But that's all you will be doing - playing. You won't be able to *do* anything with an app that you create that way. In particular, without Xcode 12, you cannot run the app on a device with iOS 14 on it, and you cannot submit the app to the App Store.

So when you say

> use older Xcode version for developing, building and deploying

...you can just delete the word "deploying"; you won't be doing that (if the word "deploying" means what it usually means).

(And you cannot easily develop an app partly with Xcode 12 and partly with Xcode 11, as some of the things you do in Xcode 12 can make the project incompatible with Xcode 11.)

Comment: Hello @matt. Do you mean once a newer Xcode version is released, we can't use the prev Xcode version for deployment? As you have mentioned "you cannot submit the app to the App Store."

Comment: Yes, I do mean that. Isn’t that the sort of thing you wanted to know?

Comment: Ahh. I think you are right, I'm not aware of this. However, just to point out to more readers, the HARD deadline of using submitting app using Xcode 12 begins from April 2021. Source here (https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/)

So, in conclusion..I see only ONE issue for using old Xcode which is, dev can't deploy and test app in proper env. Of course, the death road of this is you won't be able to deploy app using old xcode. Up to this point, you must update to new version. Correct?